# Changing base class value in c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, increment, radix

I'm facing a problem with a few inherited classes and their base class as well.

For example:

```
base class{

int x,y; // Doesnt really matter
int counter;

public:

class(int x, int y):x(x), y(y), counter(1){}

void add_counter(){counter++;}
//stuff
virtual ~base(){}
}



class1:public base{

 public:

 class1():base(1,2){}
 }
```

Every of my inherited classes (which I've a few) they all pass the x,y differently from each other. And then I want this counter to increment when I call it.

The problem I'm facing is that the counter increases ONLY on that iteration. No object is being re-constructed (because I debugged). If I call the add_counter for the class1 it will increase from 1 to 2 but if I call it again it will be the same (1 to 2).

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] of the code you are having a issue with?

Comment: Review how a class is defined: It is not `base class{..}` but `class base{...}`. And if `Derived` derives from `base`, then `class Derived : public base {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

It seems to me that you want to keep track of the number of objects constructed whose types are derived from `Base`.

In that case, you need to make `counter` a `static` member variable, which will require you to make `add_counter` a `static` member function.

However, that will require you to:

1. Decrement the count in the destructor.
2. Add a copy constructor in `Base` to make sure that objects created using a copy constructor are also counted.

Here's a simplified version of `base` to do that:

```
class base
{
   public:

     base() { inrement_counter(); }

     base(base const& copy) { inrement_counter(); }

     virtual ~base(){ decrement_counter(); }

   private:

     static int counter;
     static void inrement_counter() {++counter;}
     static void decrement_counter() {--counter;}
}

int base::counter = 0;
```

---

If you want to keep track of the number of `derived1` objects constructed, you'll need to add the bookkeeping code to `derived1`. You can create a class template to streamline that process.

Example:

```
template <typename T>
struct ObjectCounter
{
   ObjectCounter() { inrement_counter(); }

   ObjectCounter(ObjectCounter const& copy) { inrement_counter(); }

   virtual ~ObjectCounter(){ decrement_counter(); }

   static int counter;
   static void inrement_counter(){++counter;}
   static void decrement_counter(){--counter;}
};

template <typename T>
int ObjectCounter<T>::counter = 0;

class base
{
};

class derived1 : public base, public ObjectCounter<derived1>
{
};

class derived2 : public base, public ObjectCounter<derived2>
{
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   derived1 d1;
   derived2 d2;
   auto d3 = d2;

   std::cout << d1.counter << std::endl;
   std::cout << d2.counter << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Well, in fact I have a counter that it's not for the objects created but for something else. Let's say I've base class and inherited1, inherited2.... and so on. And all of those inheriteds have their own x and y (that's why it's in the base) but I've also another variable which is present in all the inherited classes as well (counter for example) and I want independently to increase or decrease it. I don't know a way to do this. It's not for each constructed object. I've only 1 object inherited constructed and I want to be able to change that counter (which is in the base). Thank you!!

Comment: @MiguelRuivo, You can't do that. The base class can't have one variable for `derived1`, a second for `derived2`, a third for `derived3`, etc. If you want to keep track of the number of `derived1` objects constructed, you'll need to add the bookkeeping code to `derived1`. You can create a class template to streamline that process.